# <FormattedMessage /> return string without any tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, bootstrap-4, react-intl

Bear with me I am not sure how to explain this issue.

I am using a Bootstrap Table to display my data, I have a searchFilters, sorting and much more functionality in the table.

When I began implementing internationalization I started by formatting directly in the text component, when I started getting too many columns and tables I moved the column names to external files which are read on need. I also needed to add dynamic translation as you can see with the headerFormatter.

The issue is the `react-intl` library adds `<span>` tags on render which cause other `<span>` tags to not function properly.

```
const headerFormatter = (col, colIndex) => {
    return ( 
        <FormattedMessage id={col.text} key={colIndex} />
    );
}
//Column Example
{dataField: 'agentNo',text: 'AgentNo', headerFormatter: headerFormatter, filter: textFilter({defaultValue:''}), sort: true},
```

Is there a way to have `<FormattedMessage />` return only a `string` in this scenario?

EXTRA INFO

Formatted:

```
<span>Date</span>
```

Non-Formatted:

```
AgentNo
<span class="react-bootstrap-table-sort-order dropup"><span class="caret"></span></span>
```

This `<span>` gets crushed over by the `<span>` of the `<FormattedMessage />`

Comment: you're returning a component `< FormattedMessage >` why do you want to have a string ? what will you do with a string? I'm not sure I understand your issue

Comment: the whole thing is in a stateless element, I want a string because it overrides other span funtionalities in the column header

Comment: the column is located under `export const entityListColumns = { columns : [`

Comment: I added a little more detail in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have decided to reorganize and to use the function `formatMessage` which is context based

Answer (score -1):

You can add your classes to the FormattedMessage component like this:

```js
const headerFormatter = (col, colIndex) => {
    return ( 
        <FormattedMessage className="react-bootstrap-table-sort-order dropup" id={col.text} key={colIndex} />
    );
}
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword in React.

Comment: you can write `className` for styling

Comment: also MayK this wont work because the `css class` is dynamically generated by `bootstrap` and gets changed when the sort state is changed to sort by ascending or descending. it will go from `react-bootstrap-table-sort-order dropup` to `react-bootstrap-table-sort-order`